# Erlang can't connect to any HTTPS url

Tags: ssl, https, erlang

The problem arose when I was trying to build rebar3, but it couldn't fetch its dependencies from Amazon S3. Debugging into the problem I found out that the erlang runtime couldn't connect to any HTTPS site, although curl or wget work completely fine. When I set `httpc:set_options([{verbose,trace}])`, I get the following output:

```
    {failed_connect,
              [{to_address,{"s3.amazonaws.com",443}},
               {inet,
                   [inet],
                   {eoptions,
                       {undef,
                           [{ssl,connect,
                                ["s3.amazonaws.com",443,
                                 [binary,
                                  {active,false},
                                  {ssl_imp,new},
                                  inet],
                                 20000],
                                []},
                            {http_transport,connect,4,
                                [{file,"http_transport.erl"},{line,135}]},
                            {httpc_handler,connect,4,
                                [{file,"httpc_handler.erl"},{line,891}]},
                            {httpc_handler,
                                connect_and_send_first_request,3,
                                [{file,"httpc_handler.erl"},{line,905}]},
                            {httpc_handler,init,1,
                                [{file,"httpc_handler.erl"},{line,242}]},
                            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                                [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}}}]}
```

Where can I look to find out what the problem is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the ssl Erlang application. Some Linux distributions split Erlang into several subpackages. You should make sure that you have the package `erlang-ssl` installed on your system.

Comment: in fact I had compiled the latest source code manually, but checking the `configure` script I saw that ssl support wasn't included. So installing libssl-dev and re-compiling the source solved the problem.

Comment: @Iman, I have the same problem when trying to reach kubernetes. I am running my elixir app on a docker which includes : `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libssl-dev`, what else can i be missing ?

Comment: @fay have you recompiled the sdk after installing libssl?

Comment: Found out i was missing `:ssl` and `:crypto` libraries in the applicaions list on my `mix.exs `file. tnx.